# Help with getting the formula for rational point $(x,y)$ on the $y^2 = x^3$

Tags: elliptic-curves

How to find formula for rational point $(x,y)$ on the $y^2 = x^3$ in term of rational parameter $t$. And also how would I write in form of $(x,y) =(f(t),g(t))$

Comment: How do I parametrize the rational points?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Show your work so that we can help. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried picking x =t and and solve for y but its not working

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** 
You can parametrise in several ways.

How about $$x=c_1t^2$$ and $$y=c_2t^3$$
where $c_1^3=c_2^2$ ?